# Unable to run the app, gradle gives error : No Such Field error

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle

I am using Amazon Face Rekognition API and getting this error at the time of sending image to aws after capturing from camera

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type
>   Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class
>   Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its
>   superclasses (declaration of
>   'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sitetrack"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1"
    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    //Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //Sugar
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    //Dimensions
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    //Library
    implementation project(':loaderLibrary')
    //Multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //GoogleServices
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    //Custom Camera
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    //AWS
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-rekognition', version: '1.11.681'



    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

This is code I am using for sending image to AWS

```
 val rekognitionClient: AmazonRekognition = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.defaultClient()
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        // Get an image object from S3 bucket.
        val image: Image = Image()
            .withS3Object(
                S3Object()
                    .withBucket("bucket")
                    .withName(name)
            )

        // Search collection for faces similar to the largest face in the image.
        val searchFacesByImageRequest = SearchFacesByImageRequest()
            .withCollectionId("face-collection-staging")
            .withImage(image)
            .withFaceMatchThreshold(70f)
            .withMaxFaces(2)

        val searchFacesByImageResult =
            rekognitionClient.searchFacesByImage(searchFacesByImageRequest)

        System.out.println("Face matching faceId"+faceId)
        val faceImageMatches =
            searchFacesByImageResult.faceMatches
        for (face in faceImageMatches) {
            println(
                objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                    .writeValueAsString(face)
            )
            println()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below dependency -

`compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1`' in your gradle file.

Comment: I have already tried this but then it gives exception like, Duplicate class org.apache.http.Consts found in modules httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and httpcore-4.4.11.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.11)

Comment: Try this - compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'

Answer (score 0):

you need to exclude also that is because you are getting exception of duplicate class

`dependencies {
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
        compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'}
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the AWS Java SDK ***V2***. It will allow you to use an alternate HTTP runtime, and avoid some of the mess with the Apache client, when working on Android.

[GitHub Issue #1180](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1180) in the AWS Java SDK V2 repo addresses this topic.

In your module-level `build.gradle`, add dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sqs:2.13.49'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client:2.13.49'
}
```

Now, initialize the Rekognition client:

```kotlin
val rekognition = RekognitionClient.builder()
    .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.create())
    .credentialsProvider(yourCredentials())
    .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
    .build()
```